# Why is 431-432MHz forbidden for use in London?

Tags: uhf, united-kingdom

The band plan says:

> Location Restriction: In addition it is very important to note that the band between 431-432MHz is not available for use if you are located anywhere within a 100km radius of Charing Cross, London.

Why is that? What is it used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The restrictions are due to MOD (Ministry of Defense, military) use. There are also some secondary business users in the spectrum. If you would look at the primary allocations in the UK, you might be surprised by the amount of spectrum allocated to the MOD. Ofcom maintains spectrum allocation data on this topic:

> UK65 - By special arrangement civil Land Mobile services may operate
>   within sub-bands 425.0-429.0 MHz, 431.0-432.0 MHz, 440.0-443.5 MHz,
>   and 445.5-449.5 MHz in agreed areas and on a non-interference basis to
>   military services. Further information can be found in the document
>   "Frequency sharing arrangements between civil and military services".

(I also used to live in the UK)

Comment: What does MOD stand for?

Comment: @PabloLU5ARC Ministry of Defense.